# BeautifulSoup .text attribute missing newline characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a bunch of product descriptions. I am strictly interested in the raw text and do not care about images or formatting.

Using BeautifulSoup I am able to locate the text. However, unfortunately the descriptions do not follow a set pattern in the HTML.

For example, the text is divided into multiple divs for this one:

https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com/product/description/pc/v2/en_US/desc.htm?productId=10000002309257&key=Uc47a341941324a2bb6f3206ce9bfb53eg.zip&token=2fa525dac3a6e26cd96c7c103d110993

Whereas for this one the text is divided into paragraphs:

https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com/product/description/pc/v2/en_US/desc.htm?productId=10000001270926&key=Uc145580c016d443caad709c8d48d56f5q.zip&token=c9165b03ddfea0d78696fbc4849efedb

And this one divides it into spans:

https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com/product/description/pc/v2/en_US/desc.htm?productId=10000001176474&key=S857a4b50929a4aaa863f9dbff5553c64m.zip&token=608f1e544017015fc3994bd7511f64cf

I am aware of the .text attribute. Unfortunately, however, if I extract the text this way newline characters are often missing. What is the easiest way to extract the text in this situation?

Here is my code:

```
session = AsyncHTMLSession()

path = 'F:\\Users\\Zé\\Products\\'

all_products = os.listdir(path)

for product_id in all_products:
    with open(path + product_id + "\\" + product_id + ".txt") as current_product_info:
        description_url = json.loads(current_product_info.read())['descriptionModule']['descriptionUrl']

        headers = {'referer': "https://aliexpress.com/item/" + product_id + ".html"}

        source = await LnN.get_source_code(description_url, False, session=session, additional_headers=headers)

        description = source.text
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe it was as simple as source.get_text('\n') and then just get rid of empty lines